# textarea analog

Tags: html

How can I post HTML to a textarea? Or in some other HTML tags?
I want it to be like a textarea, but not code text into it, just the HTML result of the code. with a scrollbar, like the following [image: something like textarea]

Answer (score 2):

Try a WYSIWIG editor like

TinyMCE - http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

or

CKEditor - http://ckeditor.com/

These will allow you to do what you are looking for hopefully.

Comment: thnx, but it generate code. But I don't know what to do in tinyMCE to see result like code into "textarea" with scrollbar; just want textarea with "html page" into it, but not page, result of php code. Can you understand me?

Comment: I think you are looking for too much out of the box. I could suggest looking for a DataGrid plugin for JQuery or the JavaScript Dojo framework which has DataGrid as part of its Dojox extension library.

Comment: Ok, just forget all, what I sad. for example, I want to see something like textarea, with html into it. withought tables, like on my picture. is it possible?

Comment: Umm no if you want to display tabular data you have to use tables. I a not sure I understand what your problem is. HTML Textareas are not meant to render html that is pasted into them.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. May be I can't to say, what I want. I want to see part of my html page into small box, like textarea. with 100 px max height. But into it textarea analog will be long html part. I just want to compress part of page to small box, like textarea. Is it possible? Can I found this analog?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your HTML to appear in a box. You don't want to be able to edit it once it is generated, but you want scrollbars down the side if the content is too big.

Try wrapping the whole thing in a <div> with scrollbars

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow:scroll">
  <!-- Your HTML table -->
</div>
```

Alternatively, you might want to put your table on a separate page and use an iframe to show it.

```
<iframe src="/yourtable.html" style="height:200px" />
```